# Reorder custom "repeat password field" for woocommerce my account registration

Tags: woocommerce, registration

Can someone take time to help me with what is stated down below?

**Goal:**
Reorder my "custom-repeat-password-field".

**Implemented code**

````
function wc_register_form_password_repeat() {
    ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_password2"><?php _e( 'Password Repeat', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password2" id="reg_password2" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['password2'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $_POST['password2'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}```
````